# Use of Custom Properties from calendar events in Outlook 365

Tags: outlook-addin, microsoft-graph-api

I created an Outlook Add-In using JavaScript Office to store custom properties into a calendar event.
I used the following call to retrieve data:
event.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(callback)
Everything works fine in the Add-In.

I want to build a Universal App and be able to retrieve the same data. But I can't find anything to do it with the current API or Graph.
Is it being developed ?
Can someone point me in the right direction to solve my problem?
How can we get the Graph Beta version?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Graph API support to get/set the data extension at present using the request below:

Create data extension:

```
POST /me/events/<id>/extensions

@odata.type": "Microsoft.Graph.OpenTypeExtension",
"extensionName": "Com.Contoso.Referral",
"companyName": "Wingtip Toys",
"expirationDate": "2015-12-30T11:00:00.000Z",
"dealValue": 10000
```

Get data extension:

```
GET /me/events/<Id>/extensions/<extensionId>
GET /users/<Id|userPrincipalName>/events/<Id>/extensions/<extensionId>
```

However it is not able to get the custom property which set from the Office add-in. If you require this feature, you can submit the feedback [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).