# Patch Microsoft.Graph Event does not add new Extension

Tags: c#, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to ***patch*** an existing Microsoft Graph Calendar [Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0) object in order to add a new [Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0) to the Event object. According to the docs this should be possible:

> Because the event resource supports extensions, you can use the PATCH
>   operation to add, update, or delete your own app-specific data in
>   custom properties of an extension in an existing event
>   instance. [More Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-body)

Here is the Update method where I'm trying to add the extension to an existing Event:

```
        public async Task<Event> UpdateEventAsync(string userId, string eventId, JsonPatchDocument<EventForUpdate> patchedEvent)
        {
            // Create a new event for updating            
            var newEvent = new Event();

            // Get the Extension data from the patch object: IDictionary<string,object>
            var extensionData = GetExtensionData(patchedEvent, newEvent);

            // Create new extension and add to event object
            var extension = new OpenTypeExtension()
            {
                ODataType = "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
                ExtensionName = EXTENSION_NAME,
                AdditionalData = extensionData,
                Id = "Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension." + EXTENSION_NAME
            };
            newEvent.Extensions = new EventExtensionsCollectionPage() { extension };

            // Create the request - unsure if Expand is necessary.
            var request = graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Events[eventId].Request();
            var reqExpanded = request.Expand($"extensions($filter=id%20eq%20'Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension.{EXTENSION_NAME}')");
            return await reqExpanded.UpdateAsync(newEvent);
        }
```

The value of extension on the returned event is always `null` -- so it seems to not be adding the next extension.  Even on subsequent calls to get all events the extension object is `null`.

I have other code creating an extension object on a new event, and that is working correctly.

*In Summary, I'd like to know how to add a new extension to an existing calendar event on a patch?*

---

Notes

I checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073470/how-to-add-an-extension-to-outlook-365-event-using-microsoft-graph) SO Question - but he's doing an Add whereas I'm doing an UpdateAsync.

I have a work around

```
  private async Task<Extension> AddExtension(string user, string eventId, IDictionary<string, object> metadata)
        {
            Extension result = null;
            // Create new extension and add to event object
            var extension = new OpenTypeExtension()
            {
                ODataType = "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
                ExtensionName = EXTENSION_NAME,
                AdditionalData = metadata,
            };
            return await graphServiceClient.Users[user].Events[eventId].Extensions.Request().AddAsync(extension);
        }
```

I call the above when I want to add extension data to an existing event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to accomplish the same, just via PostMan for now, and also fail to use patch. I suspect that excerpt from the docs is not saying quite what it appears to but rather that once the extension exists we can change it through patch.

I have succeeded with creating an extension on an existing event as follows, informed by https://stackoverflow.com/a/38471514, by rather using a POST on the extensions collection.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<upn>/calendar/events/<event-id>/extensions

{
  "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
  "extensionName": "Com.<company-name>.PlacesAvailable",
  "placesAvailable": "50"
}
```

Comment: What you have posted is the work-around I am doing. The SDK code above at the end of my post does exactly this. Specifically this line: 

graphServiceClient.Users[].Events[].Extensions.Request().AddAsync(extension);

However - I'd like to do the add during the PATCH of the event.

Comment: You can't use PATCH as the extension is actually a separate object being created and associated/attached to the existing event, thus POST is required